# Extjs set read only for all fields on form on the fly

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am try to write method which set readOnly property for all fields on the form.

My code:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.Panel,{

setReadOnlyForAll: function(bReadOnly) {

    this.cascade(function(f) {
      if (f.isFormField) {
         f.setReadOnly(bReadOnly);
      }
    });
});
```

Invoke this method from Ext.form.Panel:

```
this.setReadOnlyForAll(false);
```

But this method work so slowly.Have somebody an idea how to increase speed? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cascade` checks every child of the current container (such as an `Ext.form.Panel`) and this means you've to check if the current child is a form field or not.
So, use `Ext.form.Basic.getFields` method to get every form fields:

```
Ext.define ('Your_form_Panel', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.Panel' ,
  setReadOnlyForAll: function (bReadOnly) {
    this.getForm().getFields().each (function (field) {
      field.setReadOnly (bReadOnly);
    });
  }
});
```

Further more, I suggest you to use `Ext.define` instead of `Ext.override`.

Answer (score 7):

I was still experiencing a 9 second delay to set ~90 fields as readOnly on a form (with nested forms) with Wilk's suggestion (using ExtJS 4.1.1a).

To improve this further and reduce from 9 seconds to < 1 second I added calls to Ext.suspendLayouts() and Ext.resumeLayouts() globals to allow the framework to batch the component layouts.

```
Ext.define('My.Panel', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

  setReadOnlyForAll: function(readOnly) {
    Ext.suspendLayouts();
    this.getForm().getFields().each(function(field) {
      field.setReadOnly(readOnly);
    });
    Ext.resumeLayouts();
  }
});
```

Comment: IMHO this is correct answer. Doing layout repeatedly is major bottleneck during this operation...

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. Just add this configuration in your Form:

```
            var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {


                fieldDefaults: {
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    labelWidth: 85,
                    msgTarget: 'side',
                    readOnly : true //all fiels are in readOnly mode
                },

                defaultType: 'textfield',

                items: [{
                        fieldLabel: 'Nome',
                        name: 'nome'
                    }, {
                        fieldLabel: 'Cognome',
                        name: 'cognome'
                    }
                    ]
                }],

            });
```